# Split dataframe column with second column as delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, string, split, delimiter

I want to split a column into two columns by using the value of a second column from the same row, hence the second column value serves as the split delimiter.

I'm receiving the error `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed` which makes sense its receiving a series, not a single value, but I'm unsure how to isolate to the single row value of that second column.

Sample data:

```
    title_location                    delimiter
0   Doctor - ABC - Los Angeles, CA    - ABC -
1   Lawyer - ABC - Atlanta, GA        - ABC -
2   Athlete - XYZ - Jacksonville, FL  - XYZ -
```

Code:

```
bigdata[['title', 'location']] = bigdata['title_location'].str.split(bigdata['delimiter'], expand=True)
```

Desired output:

```
    title_location                    delimiter    title    location
0   Doctor - ABC - Los Angeles, CA    - ABC -      Doctor   Los Angeles, CA
1   Lawyer - ABC - Atlanta, GA        - ABC -      Lawyer   Atlanta, GA
2   Athlete - XYZ - Jacksonville, FL  - XYZ -      Athlete  Jacksonville, FL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `apply`.

```
bigdata[['title', 'location']]=bigdata.apply(func=lambda row: row['title_location'].split(row['delimiter']), axis=1, result_type="expand")
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `zip` for then `join` back

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame([x.split(y) for x ,y in zip(df.title_location,df.delimiter)],index=df.index,columns=['Title','Location']))
df
Out[200]: 
                     title_location delimiter     Title           Location
0    Doctor - ABC - Los Angeles, CA   - ABC -   Doctor     Los Angeles, CA
1        Lawyer - ABC - Atlanta, GA   - ABC -   Lawyer         Atlanta, GA
2  Athlete - XYZ - Jacksonville, FL   - XYZ -  Athlete    Jacksonville, FL
```